# SSL Heade HMAC calculation

Tags: c++, security, ssl, openssl, hmac

I am working on a coding few packets. For the packets I need to generate HMAC. Now I am actually trying to design it for security purpose and closely following the OpenSSL format fo packets.

How to generate HMAC for packets?
How to get the key? HOw does openssl get a key for it?

I hope you understand that the key must be available for both client and server.

My code is in c++

Comment: I think you work out what your root problem is, rather then trying to work out how to fix your solution

Comment: Wikipedia is your friend. [Read a book](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cryptography). This site is for programming questions. What have you got? Where you stuck?